# Sub-pixel precision template matching using normalized cross-correlation (normxcorr2) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencv, cross-correlation

I am using normxcorr2 function from Matlab to compute the displacement and velocity of certain region between two images. The problem is that normxcorr2 function returns result as an integer value and it doesn't evaluate sub-pixel displacemeent.
The only solution that I found is using imresize function with bicubic interpolation. I increase the size of the image 5 times and obtain better accuracy.

```
firstImage = imresize(firstImage, 5, 'bicubic');
secondImage = imresize(secondImage, 5, 'bicubic');
```

The main part of my code calculating normalized cross-correlation:

```
function [offsetX, offsetY] = calculateCrossCorrelation(refImage, targetImage, displayImages)
    if displayImages
        figure(1);
        imshowpair(refImage, targetImage, 'montage');
    end
    
    c = normxcorr2(refImage, targetImage);
    
    if displayImages
        figure();
        surf(c);
        shading flat;
    end
    % Find the peak in cross-correlation
    [ypeak,xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
    
    % Account for the padding that normxcorr2 adds
    yoffSet = ypeak-size(refImage,1);
    xoffSet = xpeak-size(refImage,2);
    
    if displayImages
        figure(3);
        imshow(targetImage);
        drawrectangle(gca,'Position',[xoffSet, yoffSet,...
            size(refImage,2), size(refImage,1)], ...
            'FaceAlpha',0);
    end
    
    offsetX = xoffSet;
    offsetY = yoffSet;
end
```

The same problem is in Python openCV library, using
*cv2.matchTemplate* with *TM_CCORR_NORMED* method.

My question is: Is using of imresize the only option to get sub-pixel precision template matching using nomxcorr2 or are there any better options?

Comment: at least opencv gives you a whole array of correlation scores. in there, you find extrema, and considering the immediate neighborhood, you can calculate the apex of a parabola or gaussian or whatever assumption you want to make about the shape of these extrema

Comment: MATLAB says it returns a matrix of doubles in the range [-1,1]. I'm not sure where you're getting an integer. [Source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html#bvh5vej-1-C).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes, correlation coefficients are in the range [-1, 1], but if we find displacements in px using following code:
    c = normxcorr2(refImage, targetImage);
    [ypeak,xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
    yoffSet = ypeak-size(refImage,1);
    xoffSet = xpeak-size(refImage,2);

the displacement is an integer value

Comment: Yes, you need to find the maximum with sub-pixel precision. Don’t just look for the pixel with the maximum value.